# Converting unsigned long long to float and losing precision

Tags: c, floating-point, unsigned-long-long-int

I have two unsigned long long numbers `l1` and `l2`. 
I cast those numbers to float and save them as `f1` and `f2`.

```
f1 = (float) l1;
f2 = (float) l2;
```

Now consider `l1` > `l2` by some arbitrary amount, say 100.

Can there be a case such that `f1` < `f2` ?. (Here `f1` is converted from `l1` which is greater than `l2`). If yes, can you please demonstrate how to find such a number?

```
sizeof(float) = 4 and sizeof(unsigned long long) = 8.
```

Comment: Yeah. If `float` is represented as an IEEE-754 single-precision number, then it only has at most 7 decimal digits of precision. So you can easily generate two huge `unsigned long long`s that differ by 100, yet they equal when converted to `float`s.

Comment: @H2CO3 The question is whether f1 < f2 is possible. I do not think it is (f1 == f2 is clearly possible).

Comment: @PascalCuoq Oops, sorry, missed that. [Here's a demo for the false equality](http://ideone.com/rE3ltT), though.

Comment: There are many wonky, unreliable and plain buggy floating-point implementations out there, both in hardware and software. Plus the C language guarantees virtually nothing beyond the some minimum limits on precision and range. I'm sure you could dig out some ancient minicomputer somewhere where this might fail if you looked hard enough but in practice on decent modern IEEE-754 systems it will be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can there be a case such that f1 < f2

No: For any rounding mode, the conversion from integer to float is increasing. As long as you do not change the rounding mode between the conversion of l1 and that of l2, f1 and f2 are in the same order as l1 and l2 (they may be equal where l1 and l2 were different, though).

Comment: In other words: it's guaranteed that if L1>L2, then F1>=F2

Comment: If both variables in fact get converted to `float`, that would be true.  I think implementations may vary with regard to e.g. `float f1 = l1; if (f1 < l2)...`, since `l2` might get converted to `float`, but I don't think it would necessarily have to be.  Even with `float f1=l1; float f2=l2;` I'm not sure some implementations (especially with a "sloppy math" option enabled) might not keep one variable in RAM as a 32-bit float while keeping the other in a 64-bit float register.

Comment: @supercat A C99 compiler that implements IEEE 754 and rightfully defines FLT_EVAL_METHOD to 0, 1 or 2 should produce the expect result, since both the `(float)` cast and the assignment to `f1` and `f2` convert to the nominal type under these conditions. With a non-IEEE 754 compiler, or FLT_EVAL_METHOD<0, anything is theoretically possible.

Comment: @supercat Many compilers define `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to 0, 1 or 2, but not rightfully so: older GCC versions (or recent versions without, say, `-std=c99`) generating 387 code. Clang generating 387 code. Most other compilers generating 387 code. I wrote up some experiments at http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/06/On-the-precise-analysis-of-C-programs-for-FLT_EVAL_METHOD-2 and http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/24/More-on-FLT_EVAL_METHOD_2